# abstract List<T>.Add not working on base constructor

Tags: c#

I have a simple class which overrides a list getter with predefined values, but, when calling the add method on the base constructor, it doesn't add the new value.

This is my code showing the error:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using NUnit.Framework;

public class SimpleTest
{
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        var child = new ChildClass();
        Assert.AreEqual(4, child.myList.Count);
    }

    private abstract class MyBaseClass
    {
        public abstract List<string> myList { get; }

        public MyBaseClass(string addThis)
        {
            myList.Add(addThis);
        }
    }

    private class ChildClass : MyBaseClass
    {
        public override List<string> myList => new List<string> { "one", "two", "three" };

        public ChildClass() : base("four")
        {
            myList.Add("dsada");
        }
    }
}
```

Why is this caused? By not having a setter the list can't be replaced by a different one but the Add method should still work for this case.

Comment: As a side note there is no reason to use `abstract` on the `myList` member in this scenario. The "best" thing to do would be to mark the `set` as `protected` and assign the value in the constructor. I would also use [`IReadOnlyList<string>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ireadonlylist-1?view=netframework-4.8) as the public type so external members cannot change the values *in* the list.

Comment: It **does** add the value. But as you noted, your code *"overrides a list getter with predefined values"*, so every time you try to get the list, that added value (and entire old list) is thrown away, and a new list is returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write `public override List<string> myList => new List<string> { "one", "two", "three" };` this is just a short-cut for the following:

```
public override List<string> myList { get { return new List<string> { "one", "two", "three" }; }
```

So you´re allways returning a completely new list.

Use this instead:

```
public override List<string> myList { get; } = new List<string> { "one", "two", "three" };
```

which will just set the initial value once for your property.

Alternativly use a backing-field:

```
private readonly List<string> _myList = new List<string> { "one", "two", "three" };
public override List<string> myList => _myList;
```

Comment: It ended up being as you said. I was too burn up and couldn't think clearly, so I couldn't see this problem and once you answered my question it suddenly made sense.

Answer (score 7):

```
public override List<string> myList => new List<string> { "one", "two", "three" };
```

You are always returning a new list when you call the getter. Either create a field that stores the list and return that one or use an auto-implemented property, which you fill in the constructor.